# Make a UIWebView Public

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` object declared in my view controller and I want to make it load a different page when the app recieves a notification while the app is running using `application:didRecieveRemoteNotification:`. I'm having trouble accessing the object from inside the appDelegate.

Any simple way to do this?

this is how I declare my web view

### .h

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

### .m

```
@synthisize webView;
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:currentPath]]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the best idea to show the web view from outside the controller. Just add method like this to controller:

```
-(void) loadFromPath:(NSString*) path {
      [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]]];
}
```

and call it in your app delegate when you need.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work! but now it says: Method '+loadFromPath:' not found(return type defaults to 'id') any ideas?

Comment: This is the code in my appDelegate:
[appViewController loadFromPath:currentPath];

Comment: that's because you haven't declared -(void) loadFromPath:(NSString*) path;   in you view controller's header.

Comment: That can't be it because I did, sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: uh,it seems to be clear to me now. +loadFromPath: means that you declared it static.       you have to declare it   -(void) loadFromPath: (with - and not  +)